# Overloading '=' does not work

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I was writing a code and I used an '=' operator to assign one object to another and a copy constructor. Here is the code

```
DJSet(const DJSet& ds)
{
    vector<Element<T>* > vec= ds.v_;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        v_.push_back(vec[i]);
    }
    //cout << "Copy Called\n";
}
DJSet operator=(DJSet ds)
{
    DJSet<T> djs;
    vector<Element<T>* > vec = ds.v_;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        djs.v_.push_back(vec[i]);
    }
    cout << "= Called\n";
    return djs;
}
```

The class DJSet contains only one Vector of `Element<T>* type` 
So when i execute the code below.

```
DJSet<string> djs_rhs;
    DJSet<string> djs_lhs;
    cin >> name;
    djs_rhs.add(name);
    cin >> name;
    djs_rhs.add(name);

    cin >> name;
    djs_lhs.add(name);
    cin >> name;
    djs_lhs.add(name);

    djs_lhs = djs_rhs;
    cout << djs_lhs << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << djs_rhs << endl;
```

It did not copy the values of the right hand side to left hand side objects And it is calling both copy constructor and '=' operator. Please help me with this. How I can continue with this ?. I can provide the whole source code if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DJSet operator=(DJSet ds)` - this takes the `ds` argument by value, so the compiler will call the copy constructor whenever the assignment operator is used. Change it to `DJSet operator=(const DJSet& ds)` to pass by reference, so that the code won't be copying here.

`DJSet<T> djs;` -- this creates a **local** object, and all the rest of the code modifies that local object. At the end of the assignment operator the local object gets destroyed, and all the work on it gets thrown away. Get rid of it.

`vector<Element<T>* > vec = ds.v_;` - this makes a local copy of the vector, which is then used to set values inside the object. It's not needed; you can copy directly from `ds.v_`, without this extra vector. Get rid of it, and change `djs.v_.push_back(vec[i]);` to `v_.push_back(ds.v_)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your operator constructs a new temporary object, and returns it. This is incorrect. The assignment operator must, by definition, assign to `this` object, and return a reference to `this`:

```
DJSet &operator=(const DJSet &ds)
{
    // Fill in the blank.

    return *this;
}
```

Also, as demonstrated, the `=` operator should take a `const` reference parameter, rather than a new temporary object.

You will need to fill in the blanks, and do what you need to do to replace the contents of `*this` with the contents of the object that's passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The op= jould be:

```
DJSet &operator=(const DJSet &ds)
{ 
    vector<Element<T>* > vec = ds.v_; 
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)   
    { 
        v_.push_back(vec[i]);
    } 
    cout << "= Called\n"; 
    return *this; 
}
```

In your implementation, you are not modif the left object but a temporary one.
Usually copy constructor and operator= should be almost identical except for the last return *this.